# Python - Initialise randomly set of different length vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I'm trying to initialize randomly a list of vectors (or 1D array). The vectors don't always have the same length.

I reproduce a small example of my problem:

```
import numpy

l_vec = [5, 6, 4]
n_vec = len(l_vec)
w = numpy.array((n_vec,)).astype(object)

for i in range(len(l_vec)):
    w[i] = numpy.random.rand(l_vec[i])
    print i, w[i]
```

If you run it, you'll see that for `w[0]`, there are no problem:

```
0 [ 0.10584519  0.90833169  0.94235319  0.34320398  0.71796362]
```

However, I have this error for the next one (when `i=1`):

`IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

How can I correct my code to be able to initialize randomly my set of (different lengths) vectors ?

If you could just tell me what's wrong with this code, I will also appreciate.

Comment: Because `w` has length 1. As an aside, if you are going to use `object` style you might as well use normal lists instead of numpy arrays.

Comment: Take another look at the [docstring for `numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).  The first argument is not the size of the array.

Comment: `w = numpy.zeros(n_vec, dtype=object)` is the correct way to make an object dtype array of size (n_vec,).

Comment: ... or `numpy.empty(n_nvec, dtype=object)` if you are going to fill in all the values later.

Comment: `np.empty` with object dtype initializes all values to `None`.  I can't imagine it saving any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `w=np.array(...)` with `w=np.empty(...)`.

```
import numpy

l_vec = [5, 6, 4]
n_vec = len(l_vec)
w = numpy.empty((n_vec,)).astype(object)

for i in range(len(l_vec)):
    w[i] = numpy.random.rand(l_vec[i])
    print(i, w[i])
```

Take a look at the docs of `np.array` and `np.empty`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a look on the docs as i never saw `np.empty()` yet